# horizontal Jquery Menu - trying to stop animation queue

Tags: jquery, css, menu, jquery-animate, submenu

Hello i'm trying to make a horizontal Menu. The Submenu is also horizontal.
The Submenu should fade in on hover and fade out on mouseleave.

My problem is that Jquery makes these animationsqueue stuff and that kills my menu. Maybe if you take a look at the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gEpvG/1/)  you see what i mean.

Comment: with stopPropagation seem to work, but i'm not sure if is want you want: `hover(function (e) {$(this).children("ul").fadeIn("slow");e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: tested and doesn't work for me. same problem. but thx anyway!

Comment: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/jquery_drop_line_tabs/#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which element do you want to be stopped? Use this instead:

```
$("#nav li").hover(function () {
    $(this).children("ul").stop(true, true).fadeIn("slow");
    },
    function(){
    $(this).children("ul").stop(true, true).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gEpvG/2/)

Comment: aaah alot better!! but do you also know how prevent this overlapping. if you hover fast from left to right over all links? or mabye somebody now a tutorial or sample menu of what im trying to do..?

Comment: @user1494353 By reducing the fadeOut milliseconds for example `.fadeOut(1);` **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gEpvG/3/)**

Comment: @user1494353 I think `.fadeOut(100)` is ideal for you.